# outlook vba script stop working

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a sorting script executed in all comming mails.

The account is shared by 5 computers and all of them have the script running.

For some reason the script works fine several times but there is a moment that it stops working, i set a debug point in the script and aparentlly the script is not being executed. The rule dont show any error.

```
Sub sortingP8(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim olkAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    'Check each attachment
    Dim totalSize As Double
    Dim containsZip As Boolean
    Dim wrongExt As Boolean
    totalSize = 0
    containsZip = False
    wrongExt = False
    somethingWrong = False
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set nonIngFolder = ns.Folders("Pqweeeq@asdasd.es").Folders("Non-ingestible Items")
    Set ingFolder = ns.Folders("Pqweeeq@asdasd.es").Folders("Ingestible Items")
    Set zipFolder = ns.Folders("Pqweeeq@asdasd.es").Folders("ZIP files")

    For Each olkAtt In Item.Attachments
        Dim extension As String
        extension = Right(LCase(olkAtt.FileName), 4)
        'If the attachment's file name ends with .zip
        totalSize = totalSize + olkAtt.Size

        If extension <> ".ppt" And extension <> ".doc" And extension <> ".pdf" And extension <> ".jpg" And extension <> ".zip" Then
            wrongExt = True
        End If
        If extension = ".zip" Then
            containsZip = True

        End If
    Next
    If (wrongExt = True Or totalSize > 10000000) Then
        Item.Move nonIngFolder
        somethingWrong = True
    End If
     If (containsZip = True And somethingWrong = False) Then
        Item.Move zipFolder
        somethingWrong = True
    End If
     If (somethingWrong = False) Then
        Item.Move ingFolder
    End If
    Set olkAtt = Nothing
End Sub
```

Any idea how this is happening in every computer?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a chance to check out the Trust Center settings in Outlook? Is Outlook macro allowed to run?

Try to run the VBA sub against the incoming email message manually and debug the code in the step-by-step manner going through each line of code and see what happens there.

Finally, you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.

Comment: The problem is that some time it works fine and every time a mail is recieved the debug mode shows up(because i set the debug point) after 1-2 hours it just not working any more. No debug mode, and the mails with attachments doesnt move to the proper folder

Comment: I have macro setting as "Notifications for digitally signed macros, all other macros disabled", Could this be a problem.
In any case i'm not able able to change them as the buttons appears disabled.
If this is the problem, how the firs times worked fine?

Comment: Could the macro setting the issue? if its that why it worked fine the first time?

Answer (score 0):

If the computer is left alone, the session disconnect timeout could be the culprit.

Comment: I have a similar issue though - have you found something different?